# load event doesn't work with addEventListener but works with onload property

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-handling

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");

body.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("test");
});

body.onload = () => {
  console.log("test");
};
```

when i use only addEventListener i don't see the message in the console but if i use onload property or use onload attribute in the html it works

Comment: [Try binding it to `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: @User863 it worked but can you tell me why didn't it worked with body element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `load` event is part of what is called the [Window-reflecting body element event handler set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#window-reflecting-body-element-event-handler-set).
Basically, these events are also accessible as HTML attributes and IDL attributes on the `<body>` element, even though the primary target is actually the `Window` object.

This is done because historically we had to use HTML attributes to set event handlers, and setting the load event in the `<body>` tag was more "natural". Since then we have gotten far better ways to set up event handlers and we can define clearly that this event fires on the `Window` object, which is more logical.
However browsers still need to support code that was listening to the `onload=""` HTML attribute, so this reflection thing has been set up.
Note that it's not just adding a new event listener, the event actually only fires on the `Window` object, but the handler can be set from the `<body>`, even overriding the ones already set on the `Window` object.

```js
window.onmessage = (evt) => console.log("handled a message from Window, is Window the currentTarget:", evt.currentTarget === window);
document.body.onmessage = (evt) => console.log("handled a message from body, is Window the currentTarget:", evt.currentTarget === window);
postMessage("hello", "*");
```

`EventTarget#addEventListener()` has no means to do this retargetting, so when you do `document.body.addEventListener("load", cb)`, you are really waiting for an event that will go through the `<body>` element, but as demonstrated above, the event actually only fires on the `Window` object.