# Trying by a script-tag in the html-flow to add eventlistener to html-body onload-event doesn't work. Is it a race condition?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, race-condition

In the middle of the html-body I have

```
<script>
function justfortest() {
    alert('teste');
}
document.getElementById('idbody').addEventListener('onload',justfortest);
</script>
```

(I copied the line just as it is in my html, without linebreaks.)

But it doesn't fire.
It's a rather short html-body, so I wonder if this simply not get called because the onload-event of the html-body has already passed, before the eventlistener is added properly, and how I could check that?

Comment: The name of the event is `load`, not `onload`.

Comment: What kind of element is `idbody`?

Comment: The `load` event only fires for elements that have asynchronously loaded contents, such as `<img>` and `<script>`.

Comment: `idbody` is the body-element, which currently looks like that: `<body id="idbody" onload="init();">`. The `init();` works fine. - I changed `onload` to `load` in the addEventListener-call. Still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Does it work if you fix the event name in `addEventListener`?

Comment: Changed it to load, and changed the alert to a `console.log`. The `console.log` doesn't show. Console doesn'T show any errors either. I will try removing the `init()`. Just a second. Result: It's still not called, even if the `init()` is removed on the `body-tag`.

Comment: I'll leave this question open, but I will for now use another approach. Don'T use too much time on it. TY

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener`.

Comment: `window.addEventListener` does work! Good enough for my task.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68143612/load-event-doesnt-work-with-addeventlistener-but-works-with-onload-property/71331935#71331935